Dynamic Task Mapping in Airflow - setting sequential dependencies amongst mapped tasks
I have a dag that queries a table in bigquery which returns a list of stored procedures to execute which can vary in both the number of stored procedures as well as the actual stored procedure needed to call for a particular pipeline run.
I am able to create the dynamic tasks and am attempting to control the sequential processing using the max_active_tis_per_dag=1.  The entire dag should fail at the point a mapped task fails.
Simple example:
Dependencies:
Task1 (output = list)-> Mapped Task2(0) - > Mapped Task(1) -> Mapped Task(2)
if mapped task 0 fails then mapped task 1 and mapped task 2 do not run (auto fail)
if mapped task 0 successful and mapped task 1 fails then mapped task 2 fails
@dag(schedule=None, start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 5, 21, 12, 00, 00), catchup=False)
def get_execution_steps():
    1) Gets steps (list of stored procedures) to execute from big query table
    2) Sorts steps into the desired processing order.  Desire is to process step 1 through x (length of list from step 1).
    3) Expand tasks so each stored procedure can be seen running as an individual task with the ability to retrigger a dag from point of failure on without rerunning prior stored procedures.
 

    @task()
    def get_and_sort_tasks():
        client=bigquery.Client()
        unsorted_task_list = client.query(bq_steps_sql, location='US')
        logger.info(repr(unsorted_task_list.result()))  
        sorted_steps_list = sorted(unsorted_task_list, key=lambda x: (int(x[0]), int(x[1])))
        logger.info(sorted_steps_list)
        sorted_task_list=[]
        for step in sorted_steps_list:
            execution_task_name = 'Execute_statement_task{}_subtask{}'.format(step[0], step[1])
            sql=step[2]
            logger.info([execution_task_name, sql])
            sorted_task_list.append([execution_task_name, sql])

    
    @task(max_active_tis_per_dag=1,  task_id= 'execute_statement_task', map_index_template="{{task_name}}")
    def execute_statements(sorted_task_list):
        logger.info(sorted_task_list)
        context = get_current_context()
        context["task_name"] = sorted_task_list[0]
        logger.info('Running:{}'.format(sorted_task_list[1]))
        client=bigquery.Client()
        query=sorted_task_list[1]
        job = client.query(query, location='US')
        logger.info(repr(job.result()))
    

    tasks = execute_statements.partial().expand(sorted_task_list=get_and_sort_tasks())


Items I've tried:
Trigger_rules appear to be at the higher task level.  I have tried setting a downstream task with a trigger_rule='one_failed' which does in fact trigger if for example mapped task 0 fails, but each individual mapped task 1 and mapped task 2 continue to process.
@task(task_id='task_exception', trigger_rule=('one_failed')
def task_exception():
   raise AirflowFailException('Dynamic Statement Failed')

Links I've looked at here and here.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html

Have a look at conditional branching and have deterministic task_ids to achieve this. Here's astronomer's doc.

@SMC hi, do you find something about this?  i also have same issue, i want stop process if one task failed. I have idea that in job, if it failed, mark other mapped tasks as failed

@Pampastu I did not find a way to do this with mapped tasks.  The best I can ascertain is that the mapped tasks are an array associated with a single task_id (thus the map index)    For instance, trigger rules (one failed) look at the status of the higher level task_id not the status of the individual mapped tasks.  As such, I am doing it old school - one dag that queries a database and writes to a variable and another dag that reads the variable to create the tasks.    If you're doing anything more elegant (ideally a single dag), I am open to suggestions.
